# How to loop through json data using an async foreach?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a basic json object like the one below which keeps track of the information related to my application. I Have a Blob URL saved as a string that I need to access and convert to base64 string using the FileReader API.

I tried using a for loop before and it worked out well for the most part. But the biggest problem is that the FileReader logic is asynchronous, and every time the for-loop runs, the FileReader seems to be skipped entirely causing the value to become `undefined`.

I've heard that the foreach method might give better results when running async functions, so I decided to give it a shot. But I'm not sure of how to reference the specific field in my array. I need to do the loop twice, once for the "mask_b64" and then once for the "spr_b64" to bind the base64 string to the array and export/download the json string.

```
{
  "objects": {
    "0": [
      {
        "name": "ads",
        "mask_b64": "none",
        "mask_offset_x": 0,
        "mask_offset_y": 0
      }
    ],
  }, 
  "sprites": {
    "0": [
      {
        "name": "RunNew",
        "basename": "RunNew_strip10.png",
        "spr_b64": "blob:https://mywebsite.net/e417be39-48a1-4feb-889b-fbbb73279f02",
        "frames": 10,
        "spr_offset_x": -1,
        "spr_offset_y": -1,
        "spr_speed": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here are my other scripts including the filereader

```js
changeBlobToBase64(temp_json_text.sprites[0])

function changeBlobToBase64(jsonArray) 
  {
  for (i = 0; i<=(jsonArray.length)-1;i++)
    {
    var blob_url = jsonArray[i]['spr_b64'];
    var new_image = blobToBase64(blob_url);

    console.log(new_image);

    jsonArray[i]['spr_b64'] = new_image;
    }
  }
```

My FileReader Script

```js
function blobToBase64(imgUrl) 
  {
  var str_to_return;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', imgUrl, true);
  request.responseType = 'blob';
  request.onload = function() 
    {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);

    reader.onload =  function(e)
      {
      str_to_return = e.target.result;
      return str_to_return;
      alert(str_to_return)
      }
    };
  request.send();
  }
```

Comment: You can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or continue your logic in [FileReader.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) callback. Also, it would be helpful if you share your FileReader logic (for-loop).

Comment: You can wait until results will come with settimeout. But its better to use promises

Comment: @DawidZbiński I have Updated the Question with the script

Comment: First you have to look at how to use the promises. Then how to make a promise loop